# Syntax for incrementing not giving expected outcome

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing a macro for excel and experiencing some issues using the "i = i + 1" code. I have used this elsewhere in my macro and it has worked fine, however for this section it is failing to increment correctly.

As this is quite a large piece of code, I have only included the section which is having issues, however if in order to properly debug this more code is required i am happy to provide this.

I have checked the syntax as has a colleague and we are struggling to find out where the issue is originating from, any help on this would be appreciated.

[image: Outcome]

All declared variables:

D

```
im lastSite As Range: Set lastSite = wsReport.Range("I2:I1000")
    Dim expectedSite As Range: Set expectedSite = wsReport.Range("H2:H1000")
    Dim expectedLocation As Range: Set expectedLocation = wsReport.Range("G2:G1000")
    Dim lostTOA As Range: Set lostTOA = wsTOAOut.Range("G2:G1000")
    Dim lostMissing As Range: Set lostMissing = wsMissing.Range("G2:G1000")

    siteCode = wsHome.Range("Q6")

    Dim last
    Dim expected
    Dim lostOut
    Dim lostMiss

    departments = wsHome.Range("R6:R20")
```

Working as intended:

```
Dim iAllocation As Integer
    For Each dept In departments
        If dept = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

    wsLBD.Range("A" & rowCounterDepartments).Value = dept
    For Each expected In expectedLocation
        If expected = dept And Not expected = "" Then
            iAllocation = iAllocation + 1
        End If
    Next
    wsLBD.Range("C" & rowCounterDepartments).Value = iAllocation
    iAllocation = 0
    rowCounterDepartments = rowCounterDepartments + 1
Next
```

Not Working as intended:

```
rowCounterDepartments = 2
departmentsOut = wsHome.Range("R6:R20")
Dim iLoss As Integer
Dim iMissing As Integer
For Each lostOut In lostTOA
    If lostOut = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    For Each deptOut In departmentsOut
        If lostOut = deptOut And Not lostOut = "" Then
            iLoss = iLoss + 1
        End If
    Next
    wsLBD.Range("B" & rowCounterDepartments).Value = iLoss
    iLoss = 0
    rowCounterDepartments = rowCounterDepartments + 1
Next
```

The output expected should be a total count for each department, however it is only outputting a 1 or 0 per line

Comment: Could it be that there are 0 or 1 `deptOut` on your `departmentsOut` ?

Comment: `And Not lostOut = "" ` this appears redundant, since an empty `lostOut` causes an `Exit for` the line above.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] and some example data? Screenshots might help as well. • Also it is unclear what `lostTOA` is. We need to see the relevant code parts and their variable declarations (use `Option Explicit`).

Comment: Many thanks for your quick responses, apologies i should have included the piece of code that is working as intended (see above) and includes a syntax that is very similar. Also this is the first project i have ever had to use VBA for so i am very much learning as i go.

Comment: @Craig_kitch Your screenshot is not really helpfull because the row/column numbers are cut off, so we still don't know where all the range references are linked to. • Can you please also include (in words) what your code should do? What's your goal?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot do the counting with a formula like `COUNTIF`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ of course, this piece of code should be counting the total assets for each department that have been lost vs the total that were allocated for easy and quick analysis of the audits that are completed monthly, currently this has to be done manually so hoping that this automation will save time in the long run.

As you can see the total allocation is currently working and providing a total per department, however when attempting to count and sum the total loss the count fails to increment properly.

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- just step through your code and inspect the variables, and you will find the issue.

Comment: If you just want to count how often a specific value (department) appears in another range you can use a simple `=COUNTIF` formula, you don't need VBA then.

Comment: Looking at your script side by side, your second bit doesn't really know how to correlate those departments in the screenshot, with your losses. I mean, there is nothing to check that. It should be a `for each dept in screenshotdepts` kind off, then if `dept = deptout` (from your inner loop), do your stuff. In other words, change your `lostTOA As Range: Set lostTOA = wsTOAOut.Range("G2:G1000")` to `wsLBD.Range("B2:B7")` (you might want to use a dynamic lastrow variable).

Comment: @DarXyde Thank you for the advice, i have just tried this, however it still gives the same output, it appears to be the iLoss = iLoss + 1 and "wsLBD.Range("B" & rowCounterDepartments).Value = iLoss" part of the code that is giving me the error.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for the input, i could use the =COUNTIF formula for this part, however the aim of the macro was automation overall and to reduce the amount of formula in the spreadsheet to 0 if possible. The aim of that being to reduce the amount of error or accidental deletions of this audit when used by other departments or sites.

Comment: @Craig_kitch It is a very bad idea to replace all formulas with VBA. Formulas are actually Excel's strength. Instead protect your sheets and chose which cells/ranges should not be locked and can be edited by other users. This is a much better way and much easier to maintain later, users can not edit or delete formulas accidentally and still can insert/edit data. Do some decent research on how sheet protection works and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved, i re-wrote this piece of code and it was a syntax error on my part, a couple of the pieces were the wrong way round.